# Can't ssh by name with more than 3 robots

Tags: ros, ssh, network-setup, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a main computer to launch the ros nodes in 4 robots. These robots have odroids. I can `ssh` into the robots by name:

```
ssh odroid@odroid-machine1.local
ssh odroid@odroid-machine2.local
ssh odroid@odroid-machine3.local
ssh odroid@odroid-machine4.local
```

I can ssh by name to all the robots except 1 `odroid@odroid-machine4.local`. To that one I need to ssh by ip address but I need to ssh by name to launch the nodes on it.

The network is done with a router, and something funny is happening. If I do not connect the router to internet I cannot ssh `odroid-machine4.local` by name, only by ip address. If a connect the router to internet everything is fine. The thing is that for some of my experiments I need to move to a place where I do not have internet access.

I think I might have some configuration problems but I do not know how to debug them.

Today I reinstalled Ubuntu from zero on `odroid-machine4.local`. Then I reinstalled all the software and configured the network as I always do for all the robots. I was able to ssh `odroid-machine4.local` by name. Then I connected all the robots to the network and again `odroid-machine4.local` was not recognized by name. It was until I connected the router to internet that I was able to ssh by name.

I even tried with a different router and I have the same problem.

I think I need to configure something but I don't know what.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244582/can%27t-ssh-by-name-with-more-than-3-robots/) by [Luis Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/14101/luis-ruiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2016-09-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-27**:
I sympathise, but technically, this isn't really a ROS-related question, correct?

**Comment by [Luis Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/14101/luis-ruiz/) on 2016-09-27**:
Well, I use it on robots using ROS, so maybe someone had this issue and can guide me.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-27**:
So which device is performing the DNS server role here? The router? Or are you depending on bonjour / avahi-like services? Can all the hosts resolve all other hostnames? Is it just the desktop machine that can't resolve the `odroid-machine4` name, or do all hosts have problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I asked [here](http://superuser.com/questions/1128835/cant-ssh-by-name-if-router-is-not-connected-to-internet) and solved the problem. I had to configure the `/etc/hosts`  files properly.

---

Originally posted by [Luis Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/14101/luis-ruiz/) with karma: 114 on 2016-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-28**:
A name resolution issue then? Strange that it did work for `odroid1` to `3`, but not for `4`. I would've expected it to never work, or always.

Thanks for reporting back.